# Swiping image slider swiping over too far

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, swipe

I attempted to add a swiping function to my slider to allow users to swipe through the images on their touchable devices. It hasn't turned out the best. When swiping at the images they do not slide over all of the way and then when I get to the end of the gallery (end of fourth image), the slider goes blank (goes white) and then it goes back to normal after a while.

I have added the important code to this question, as well as added a [Fiddle to try it out](https://jsfiddle.net/m92wu68z/).

The fiddle doesn't replicate the issue, so if you would like to see what this is doing, please [go here to see it live](http://optimumwebdesigns.com/projects/eslich-wrecking). Scroll about halfway down and then you will see the slider.

The example I used had three images instead of four and I am thinking this may be my issue, but when I remove my 4th image (a repeat of the first image for a smoother transition back to the first), the issue is still present. I'm 99% sure the issue resides within the javascript, but I can't locate it.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong or how to improve this?

Please note. I am putting the full code for this function, but I believe the issue resides within the move or end function here:

```
move: function(event) {
          // Continuously return touch position.
          this.touchmovex =  event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
          // Calculate distance to translate figure.
          this.movex = this.index*this.slideWidth + (this.touchstartx - this.touchmovex);
          // Defines the speed the images should move at.
          var panx = 100-this.movex/6; // was /6
          if (this.movex < 600) { // Makes the figure stop moving when there is no more content.
            this.el.figure.css('transform','translate3d(-' + this.movex + 'px,0,0)');
          }
          if (panx < 100) { // Corrects an edge-case problem where the background image moves without the container moving.
            this.el.imgSlide.css('transform','translate3d(-' + panx + 'px,0,0)');
          }
        },

        end: function(event) {
          // Calculate the distance swiped.
          var absMove = Math.abs(this.index*this.slideWidth - this.movex);
          // Calculate the index. All other calculations are based on the index.
          if (absMove > this.slideWidth/2 || this.longTouch === false) {
            if (this.movex > this.index*this.slideWidth && this.index < 2) {
              this.index++;
            } else if (this.movex < this.index*this.slideWidth && this.index > 0) {
              this.index--;
            }
          }      
          // Move and animate the elements.
          this.el.figure.addClass('animate').css('transform', 'translate3d(-' + this.index*this.slideWidth + 'px,0,0)');
          this.el.imgSlide.addClass('animate').css('transform', 'translate3d(-' + 100-this.index*50 + 'px,0,0)');
```

Full code:

```
if (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints) {

  $('#slider').addClass('ms-touch');

  $('#slider').on('scroll', function() {
    $('.slide-image').css('transform','translate3d(-' + (100-$(this).scrollLeft()/6) + 'px,0,0)');
  });

} else {

  var slider = {

    el: {
      slider: $("#slider"),
      figure: $(".figure"),
      imgSlide: $(".slide-image")
    },

    slideWidth: $('#slider').width(),
    touchstartx: undefined,
    touchmovex: undefined,
    movex: undefined,
    index: 0,
    longTouch: undefined,

    init: function() {
      this.bindUIEvents();
    },

    bindUIEvents: function() {

      this.el.figure.on("touchstart", function(event) {
        slider.start(event);
      });

      this.el.figure.on("touchmove", function(event) {
        slider.move(event);
      });

      this.el.figure.on("touchend", function(event) {
        slider.end(event);
      });

    },

    start: function(event) {
      // Test for flick.
      this.longTouch = false;
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.slider.longTouch = true;
      }, 250);

      // Get the original touch position.
      this.touchstartx =  event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

      // The movement gets all janky if there's a transition on the elements.
      $('.animate').removeClass('animate');
    },

    move: function(event) {
      // Continuously return touch position.
      this.touchmovex =  event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
      // Calculate distance to translate figure.
      this.movex = this.index*this.slideWidth + (this.touchstartx - this.touchmovex);
      // Defines the speed the images should move at.
      var panx = 100-this.movex/6; // was /6
      if (this.movex < 600) { // Makes the figure stop moving when there is no more content.
        this.el.figure.css('transform','translate3d(-' + this.movex + 'px,0,0)');
      }
      if (panx < 100) { // Corrects an edge-case problem where the background image moves without the container moving.
        this.el.imgSlide.css('transform','translate3d(-' + panx + 'px,0,0)');
      }
    },

    end: function(event) {
      // Calculate the distance swiped.
      var absMove = Math.abs(this.index*this.slideWidth - this.movex);
      // Calculate the index. All other calculations are based on the index.
      if (absMove > this.slideWidth/2 || this.longTouch === false) {
        if (this.movex > this.index*this.slideWidth && this.index < 2) {
          this.index++;
        } else if (this.movex < this.index*this.slideWidth && this.index > 0) {
          this.index--;
        }
      }      
      // Move and animate the elements.
      this.el.figure.addClass('animate').css('transform', 'translate3d(-' + this.index*this.slideWidth + 'px,0,0)');
      this.el.imgSlide.addClass('animate').css('transform', 'translate3d(-' + 100-this.index*50 + 'px,0,0)');

    }

  };

  slider.init();
}


.animate {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

#company-slider-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

div#slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

div#slider .figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.ms-touch.slider {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;

  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* Hides the scrollbar. */

  -ms-scroll-chaining: none;
  /* Prevents Metro from swiping to the next tab or app. */

  -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  /* Forces a snap scroll behavior on your images. */

  -ms-scroll-snap-points-x: snapInterval(0%, 100%);
  /* Defines the y and x intervals to snap to when scrolling. */
}

.figure2 {
  animation: 20s company-slider infinite;
  margin: 0;
}

@keyframes company-slider {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  35% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  55% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  60% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  90% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}

.slide-wrapper img {
  width: 25%;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.slide:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, black);
}


<div id="company-slider-section">
            <div class="section-blocks left">
            <div id="slider" class="slider">
              <figure class="figure figure2">
                <div class="slide-wrapper">
                  <div class="slide"><img src="/images/work/projects/eslich/es-test1.jpg" alt class="slide-image"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-wrapper">
                  <div class="slide"><img src="/images/work/projects//desktop-service.jpg" alt class="slide-image"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-wrapper">
                  <div class="slide"><img src="/images/work/projects//es-test2.jpg" alt class="slide-image"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-wrapper">
                  <div class="slide"><img src="/images/work/projects//es-test1.jpg" alt class="slide-image"></div>
                </div>
              </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```